# WebAuthenticationBroker in a Universal App with Login With Amazon

Tags: amazon-web-services, win-universal-app, login-with-amazon

I'm working on a new Universal App (first time) and I am trying to use Login with Amazon as my authentication provider.  Amazon doesn't provide an SDK for .NET for LWA so I'm left trying to figure it out on my own.

Here is what I am doing so far:

```
var redirectUrl = "https://localhost/";
var baseUrl = "https://amazon.com/ap/oa?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&response_type=code&scope=profile";
var uri = new Uri(baseUrl);
var redirectUri = new Uri(redirectUrl);
WebAuthenticationResult webAuthenticationResult = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(WebAuthenticationOptions.None, uri, redirectUri);
```

This gets me to the login with Amazon page just fine, and allows me to login, but handing off back seems to be a problem.

Any and all help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Amazon LWA Developer Guide](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/lwa/dev/docs/website-developer-guide._TTH_.pdf)

Page 25.

[image]

As I can see you missed some required parameters - **scope** and **redirest_uri**. Specify them properly and probably it will work.

For a Universal App, make sure you enable the Internet Client & Server Capability.

Comment: Yes, I did copy-paste my baseUrl string a little poorly.  I updated my question.  If you read the manual on WebAuthenticationBroker, not specifying a redirect_uri defaults the redirect_uri to the app's uri.

Comment: 1. Specify redirect uri (for example http://localhost) on this page in section "web settings -> Allowed Return URLs" https://sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/homepage.html

2. WebAuthenticationResult WebAuthenticationResult = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(
                    WebAuthenticationOptions.None,
                    new Uri("https://www.amazon.com/ap/oa?client_id=CLIENT_ID&response_type=code&scope=profile&redirect_uri=http://localhost"),
                    new Uri("http://localhost"));

Comment: Yea, that gets me the login with amazon page, but not back to my app.  I'll edit my question to make it clear that my problem is handing the response back to my app.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used WebAuthenticationBroker and you haven't provided the error message you're getting, so I have to do some guessing here...

Scanning the MSDN docs for WebAuthenticationBroker, it looks like it's meant to work with the Implicit grant flow (where an access token is returned after login/consent) vs. the Authorization grant flow (where you get back a code you must then exchange for an access token).

So if it's getting back an Authorization grant response instead of an Implicit grant response, it could be throwing an error because it's missing expected fields.

Try changing your `response_type` from `code` to `token` and see if that helps. If it doesn't, please post some more detail on the error you're getting.